# Did Tomura Shigaraki become stronger than All Might before he lost One for All?

Tags: my-hero-academia

According to the last version of the official stats Tomura's power jumped from 2/5 to 6/6 S+ . I think this was when

> he awakened the full power of his decay, which made him able to decay a whole city .

but after that on top of that,

> he received All for One which a bunch of quirks attained already, like super regeneration, air cannon and black tendrils

So, with all these new powers attained, did he even surpass All Might former power? Did the last stats took in consideration these last powers he got in the manga or were they made before these events?

Comment: Shig has been worked on time and time again by that dr according to the flashbacks and how the last season ended

Answer (score 1):

Yes. But is complicated.

If you are asking this i guess you are up to date, (If not you shouldnt be asking this).

So Izuku and the others managed to barely subdue him for a moment and they were all going with everything they had.

Now, Izuku still couldnt fully use his 100% without hurting himself too fast and Shigaraki "improvement" was imperfect. Besides Izuku had Eraserhead and the others giving him back up.

The question is how powerful is corrently AFO.

Based on how hurt was Sensei, he probably couldnt use fully his Quirk during his last fight against All Might, but one would assume he has stolen some new Quirks in his years of recovery, add to that Decay, and a perfected Shigaraki should be able to easily kill All Might in his prime.